# DynamoDB table.get_item() get executed twice

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am working on to create DAO layer for few tables.
Since there are many methods that will be used across different DAO's I thought of using a parent class for all of them and implement few common methods. I am passing `table_name` and `__name__` attribute to parent class so that it will create logger of child class and create the right table variable.

Below is how I am doing it.

```
class Parent(object):    
    def __init__(self, class_name, table_name):
        ddb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name=constants.AWS_REGION)
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.table = ddb.Table(table_name)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(class_name)

    def get_record(self, **kwargs):
        try :
            self.logger.info(f"self type => {type(self)}")
            record = self.table.get_item(**kwargs)
            self.logger.info(f"record => {record}")
            record = record['Item']
            if record == {}:
                raise NoRecordException(f"No record with {kwargs} found in {self.table_name}")
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            raise e
        return record



class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, class_name=__name__, table_name="Child")
        self.record = {}

    def get_child_record(self, id):
        return self.get_record(Key={"id": id})
```

When I am calling `Child().get_child_record(id)`, I see, `self.table.get_item` getting executed twice. Not only that, 2nd time it is getting executed with `record` itself instead of args I called the function with, and getting below error as a result.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

I am unable to understand what could be triggering this. I thought it could be because of super() so I replaced that with parent class name, but to no vain.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made wrong call to `get_record()` , which made me think things are getting repeated. Was able to identify it, when tested by calling method using both child and parent object.